# MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and System Start Drivers Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, driver, updates, boot, windows-server-2016

I am trying to figure out when MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT operations are performed in relation to System Start drivers (Start=1) on Windows 10 / Server 2016.

Assume the source and target are on the same volume, so it is a move instead of a copy.

This is what is happening with my System Start minifilter driver on Windows 10. As you know, Windows 10 / Server 2016 now keeps loaded SYS files locked.

- c:\windows\system32\drivers\mydriver.sys version 1 is loaded at System Start.
- upgrade installer tries to update mydriver.sys to version 2 but file is in use.
- upgrade installer schedules a move on reboot for the version 2 file.
- Reboot occurs
- According to my tests, the system is *still* trying to load version 1 of mydriver.sys!
- System then moves in mydriver.sys version 2.

Is this correct?  If so, that raises three questions:

1) How is it moving in version 2 after version 1 is already loaded and running?

2) How is Windows updating its own System Start drivers on Windows 10?

3) Is it required to reboot twice to update System Start drivers via MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT with Windows 10 /Server 2016?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: *The system moves the file immediately after AUTOCHK is executed* - so all drivers with system start (1) already loaded. so you need another solution. you need rename your file from say `mydrv.sys` to `mydrv.sys.v1` and then create new `mydrv.sys` and at the end call delete after reboot `mydrv.sys.v1` .

Comment: Thanks. But then the question becomes, how is the SYS file being updated at all?  Apparently it is being moved after the old file was loaded, and presumably locked.

Comment: i don't special research how windows update files, but possible solution how i say - first rename file - it is possible even if file is mapped. then create new file with well known name (now it free) and finally delete renamed version after reboot